# A problem regarding continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, continuity

Problem: Let $c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $c$. If for every positive $\delta>0$ there is a point $y \in (c- \delta, c+\delta)$ such that $f(y)=0$, prove that $f(c)=0$

Attempt: Let $E_n =(c-1/n, c+1/n)$. Let $y_n \in E_n$. Evidently for $\{y_n\}$,  the limit is $ c$. Being continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ at $c$, by sequential criterion $f(c)=0$.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. To precise what you did.

If one of the $y_n$ is equal to $c$ you're done... $f(y_n)=f(c)=0$ as desired.

If not, you found a sequence $\{y_n\}$ converging to $c$ and such that $f(y_n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. As $f$ is supposed to be continuous at $c$ you have 
$$ f(c) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) = 0$$